# How to center link button vertically and horizontally inside image banner

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I need to center the image properly inside the banner.
Centered horizontally and vertically.

Here is the jsfiddle I made. The center of the button must be between the vertical red line and also centered vertically.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rubinoff/KWRkQ/)

```
  <table  width="100%"  border="0px" style="background:transparent">
   <tr>
    <td height="305px">
   <div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="#" class="botonConocer"  >Conocer más</a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/Grass.jpg" style="width:100%;height:305px" class="img-responsive" />



    </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: fix your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

if your button already positioned absolute in the css, you can add this style to make it show in the middle

```
.botonConocer {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -28px 0 0 -82px;
}
```

in margin you set it to negative number which equal to half your height and half your width, then it will show in the middle with the position it's relative to, so if you want to make it appear in the middle of your container, you should add this to your container

```
.container {position: relative}
```

here's the results in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KWRkQ/1/)

Comment: This solution won't work if i increase the button text.

Comment: well, this solution is used if you know already the width and the height of your button and it's height and width is fixed. where you should edit the margin with negative half the width and height.